# How to handle two datagridviews errors with one method?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, event-handling

I have task to create method which have to handle two `DataGridView` errors and display them in screen.

I have this method which works perfecetly when using one datagridview, but I how  can handle both datagridviews errors with one method?

```
public void gridErr(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    // Don't throw an exception when we're done.
    e.ThrowException = false;
    // Display an error message.
    string txt = "Klaida su " + dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText + "\n\n" + e.Exception.Message;
    MessageBox.Show(txt, "Klaida", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    // If this is true, then the user is trapped in this cell.
    e.Cancel = false;
}
```

My friend told that it can be done by not using events.

Comment: You can either define a general event handler reacting on both grids or you might want to create a method containing your code and call this from within separate event handler methods. I'd prefer the second...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code would work perfectly for 2 different controls, apart from the explicit reference to dataGridView1. You should change that to refer to a grid variable which is inferred from the sender:

```
var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
```

Then that method can work as an error handler for any grid.